# Running a C code developed in IAR on Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio, iar

I have a `C` code developed on `IAR`. This code was executed on a hardware with ARM processor that has a screen for remote control of a physical machine.

Between this program (hardware) and the physical machine, a `TCP` connection is established through LAN cable, and it was possible to exchange messages.

Now I want to run this code on Windows to communicate with that physical machine through the computer.

Is this possible?

In fact, I want to see the same screen on the computer and send the message through the computer to the physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code. You should have a look on Cygwin as a Posix conform environment that comes with a gcc and mintty as a nice terminal emulator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).